# Document generic type parameters in JSDOC

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

In [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) there exists the possibility to document the exact types of array contents [like this](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html):

```
/** @param {Array.<MyClass>} myClasses An array of MyClass objects. */
TestClass.protoype.someMethod = function( myClasses ){
   myClasses[0].aMethodOnMyClass();
}
```

This makes code completion in IDEs like WebStorm actually provide the right type information after the `[0].`. This works well for the Array type, however I have my own collection types where I would like to make use of this feature, too. The problem is I cannot find the right syntax (maybe because there is none, yet). I would love to be able to declare my class somehow like this:

```
/**
 * @typeparam {T} the type parameter
 * @constructor {Test2.<T>}
 * */
Test2 = function(){};

/**
 * @returns {T} a value of type T, where T is the generic type parameter of Test2
 */
Test2.prototype.getGenericValue = function(){}
```

This syntax or feature does not work with my IDE and is not listed [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types), so I am wondering whether there is a syntax for this use-case, either for WebStorm or any other JS authoring tool.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the meantime, support for this feature has been finalized and is now documented on [the Closure Compiler JSDOC page for generics](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types).

Basically it works like this for ES6 classes:

```
/** @template T */
class Foo {
  /** @return {T} */
  get() { ... };

  /** @param {T} t */
  set(t) { ... };
}
```

... and like this for pre-ES6 code:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @template T
 */
Foo = function() { ... };
```

and

```
/** @return {T} */
Foo.prototype.get = function() { ... };

/** @param {T} t */
Foo.prototype.set = function(t) { ... };
```

WebStorm 7.0 [did not](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7522) support this feature at the time the original answer was written, but as of today (2019) all JetBrains IDEs understand this syntax, properly.

Comment: Can you show an example of this being implemented?

Answer (score 44):

You can try using `@template` tag (undocumented tag used in Google Closure library - extremely limited form of generics). Something like:

```
/**   
 * Search an array for the first element that satisfies a given condition and   
 * return that element.   
 * @param {Array.<T>|goog.array.ArrayLike} arr Array or array   
 *     like object over which to iterate.   
 * @param {?function(this:S, T, number, ?) : boolean} f The function to call   
 *     for every element. This function takes 3 arguments (the element, the   
 *     index and the array) and should return a boolean.   
 * @param {S=} opt_obj An optional "this" context for the function.   
 * @return {T} The first array element that passes the test, or null if no   
 *     element is found.   
 * @template T,S   
 */  
goog.array.find = function(arr, f, opt_obj) {    
   var i = goog.array.findIndex(arr, f, opt_obj);    
   return i < 0 ? null : goog.isString(arr) ? arr.charAt(i) : arr[i];  
};
```

WebStorm uses this tag for type hinting - i.e. if we pass array of strings to goog.array.find in the sample above , IDE will know that return type is string, so string completion options will be suggested etc.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for... The post that looks related is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/closure-compiler-discuss/-5PNxtu5E1k).

Comment: Thanks, I just found this out myself from [this YouTrack issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1208) and [this Closure Compiler Changeset](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/detail?spec=svn64d22457ddca24b07370f711276a449273bd6330&r=0eb41cabc9ba5463e3a34ea2fd900a8dd54f2136). Is there support for this on the class level? My tests indicate that this works for "function local type parameters" only.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works fine for me in WebStorm 8.

```
/** @type {Array.<MyPair.<Event, Array.<Thought>>>} */
scope.pairs = [];

/**
 * @template TFirst, TSecond
 */
function MyPair(first, second){
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}
/** @type {TFirst} */
MyPair.prototype.first = null;
/** @type {TSecond} */
MyPair.prototype.second = null;

...
function Event(){}
...
...
function Thought(){}
...
```

Comment: In above example, it worked with Event and Thought object as well.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime a lot of this has been implemented in WS8, but still there are open issues that will only be fixed in WS9 - see my answer and the linked issues.