# Is there a JavaScript documentation generator that supports parameter shifting and "polymorphism"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

The more "magic" your JavaScript library is, the less likely it is that you're able to use a documentation generator.

Is anyone aware of a documentation generator that allows documentation of functions with parameter shifting/parametric polymorphism?

```
function example(required, optional, callback) {
   if(typeof optional === 'function' && typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       callback = optional;
       optional = 'DEFAULT VALUE';
   }

   // do work here
}
```

Which can be called as follows:

```
example(required, optional, function() {
  // do work
});

example(required, function() {
  // do work
});
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, with the exception of "use a generic comment/documentation block".

This is related, but not a duplicate of:
[Document generic type parameters in JSDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017627/document-generic-type-parameters-in-jsdoc)

Comment: I updated my answer by I can't really test it. Maybe JSDOC does support overloading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It looks like JSDoc supports overloading of functions](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/issues/detail?id=276) with the `@name fun @name fun^2` I think the following communicates your intent clearly

```
/**
    @name example
    @function
    @param {string} required
    @param {Function} callback
 */
 /**
    @name example^2
    @function
    @param {string} required
    @param {string} [optional='DEFAULT VALUE']
    @param {Function} callback
 */
function example() {
    if(typeof optional === 'function' && typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       callback = optional;
       optional = 'DEFAULT VALUE';
    }

    // do work here
}
```

However, in your case, I think it would be easiest if you just switched your optional parameter to the end, then you won't need overloading

```
/**
 * @param required
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @param {String} [optional='DEFAULT VALUE'] 
 */
function example(required, callback, optional) {
   if (typeof optional === 'undefined') {
       optional = 'DEFAULT VALUE';
   }   
   // do work here
}
```

Comment: I have not tested this, however, you have proposed a solution that satisfied my requirements in addition to a workaround. This is what I look for in an answer. Thanks for your sleuthing.