# JSDoc: how to document a function that returns an instance of a passed constructor?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

For instance, I have the following function:

```
function createInstanceOf(ObjectConstructor) {
  return new ObjectConstructor;
}
```

I want to make WebStorm autocompletion working when I pass a class as an argument. For example: if I call `createInstanceOf(ClassA)` I want to see autocompletion for `ClassA` instance, if I call `createInstanceOf(ClassB)` – for `ClassB` instance. So JSDoc function has to be generic.

It's easy to define a generic function with JSDoc and make `@return` value type be the same as `@param`, but I've found no way to treat `@param` type as a constructor for returned object.

So this doesn't work:

```
/**
 * @param {T} ObjectConstructor
 * @returns {T}
 * @template T
 */
function createInstanceOf(ObjectConstructor) {
  return new ObjectConstructor;
}
```

I also tried to make it working this way:

```
/**
 * @param {function(new:T)} ObjectConstructor
 * @returns {T}
 * @template T
 */
function createInstanceOf(ObjectConstructor) {
  return new ObjectConstructor;
}
```

But maybe I use closure types wrong, or WebStorm can't resolve such generic types.

If there're several solutions for JSDoc, I'd like to find out which ones work specifically with WebStorm IDE autocompletion.

Thank you

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017627/document-generic-type-parameters-in-jsdoc) might help.

Comment: @RichardSzakacs, thanks for the suggestion. I've already tried closure types suggested in the answers. Updated my question: added one more not working example of what I've come up with

Comment: You're welcome! I just deleted my original answer, since I'm looking for this feature myself too, but apparently at the moment only Google Closure supports the `@template`, JSDoc doesn't have any documentation about it and I'm not able to tell, when are we gonna get a working solution for this feature. But I'm hoping...

Comment: I would also be interested in a better approach... currently I'm just working around using something like `/** @type {SomeType} */ const instance = createInstanceOf(SomeType);` everywhere I'm using such a method

Answer (score 11):

You probably don't need this anymore, but I too have been stuck on this for months so for other people wondering, you can do it like this:

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {new() => T} ObjectConstructor
 * @returns {T}
 */
function createInstanceOf(ObjectConstructor) {
  return new ObjectConstructor;
}
```

[Got the answer from this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics)

Comment: Thank you for this! I was also stuck for months with this issue, and your answer was the only way that worked.

Comment: Yeah, that helped me a lot too! JSDoc is tricky!