# How to document generic type parameters?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Assuming a generic type below, what should I use in place of `???` to properly document `T`?

```
/**
 * ??? The description of T.
 */
class MyClass<T> {
}
```

In C# I'd use [`<typeparam>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#typeparam). Is there an official JSDoc equivalent?

Comment: Related?: [Document generic type parameters in JSDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017627)

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah I saw that, but It's unclear how it applies to my case. What should I write instead of `???` above?

Comment: It's also unclear to me, to be honest. Hence the question mark. I've read it but I'm not sure how it applies to TS.

Comment: Looking at some more sources, perhaps all you need is `@template T - some description here` see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) (it's TS documentation but explains how to annotate JS code) and [here is the full description of `@template`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types). Annoyingly [the JSDoc documentation doesn't mention `@template`](https://jsdoc.app/)

Comment: @VLAZ That could be it, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

VLAZ notes in the comments that `@template` works but isn't mentioned in the official JSDoc documentation. It is, however, mentioned in [Typescript's own JSDoc reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template):

> You can declare type parameters with the `@template` tag. This lets you make functions, classes, or types that are generic:

Example:

```
/**
 * Description of the class MyClass.
 * 
 * @template T Description of the type parameter T.
 */
class MyClass<T> {
    constructor(public readonly x: T) {}
}
```

The text *"Description of the type parameter T."* appears in the Typescript Playground when I hover over the occurrence of `T` in the constructor, so this does seem to work.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgRBTAzgYwE4EsAOAXdB7AO0jwDNJsALeSZAGwENFFIBZATwGEGmA6KGfpAAC2eAFtMDUZAAqcJGiy5CxMpWrY2mapnqp6Y+KNSy+0YODqNm7LtYA8MgHyQA3lEifkhRNlQBXZGw8VAAKTH8AI1p0ZEhUeHoAE0JaNkgADwAuWQBKNwBfcCKgA)

Answer (score 3):

for those who are looking the TsDoc, you can use the https://tsdoc.org/pages/tags/typeparam/

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * @typeParam T - Description of T
 */
class MyClass<T> {

}
```