# Why isn't VS Code providing autocomplete for methods on the return type of my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, methods

I am working on a web development project using Visual Studio Code and JavaScript. In my code, I have a function that creates a new div element and assigns it to a variable named `newDiv`. Here is the code:

```js
function createNode(tag,id) {
    let newNode = document.createElement(tag)
    newNode.id = id;
    return newNode;
}

let newDiv = createNode("div", "identificador1");
```

However, when I type "newDiv." in my code editor, VS Code does not offer any methods or properties for `newDiv`, even though it is a div element.

I expected to see a list of available methods, such as `classList`, `getAttribute`, and `appendChild`, but nothing appears.

I have tried the following solutions:

- Restarting VS Code
- Checking that I am typing the period (".") correctly
- Checking there are no typos.
- Explicitly specifying the type of `newDiv` as `HTMLDivElement` works, and VS Code starts to offering methods, but  the word "as" is causing an Uncaught SyntaxError. like this:

  ```
  let newDiv = createNode("div", "identificador1") as HTMLDivElement;
  ```

None of these solutions have worked for me. Can someone please help me understand why VS Code is not offering methods for `newDiv`, and how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything to tell static analysis about the expected types of the inputs for your function. In VS Code, you can do this for JavaScript with [JSDoc annotations](https://jsdoc.app/index.html):

```js
/**
 * @param tag {keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap}
 * @param id {string}
 */
function createNode(tag,id) {
    let newNode = document.createElement(tag)
    newNode.id = id;
    return newNode;
}
```

The static analysis of VS Code powered by TypeScript will be able to infer the return type now based on the input type annotations and the body of the function. (It will suggest an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) of all type values in `HTMLElementTagNameMap` since it can't do better without generics). If you want the `HTMLDivElement` type exactly, you will have to hint it using a `/**@type {HTMLDivElement}*/ let newDiv = createNode(...);`.

You could get better return type inference if you could use better generics (which TypeScript has) in JSDoc. It seems that VS Code doesn't support TypeScript generics in type annotations very deeply right now. I tried the following just as a hypothesis and such syntax doesn't seem to be supported:

```js
/**
 * @template T {keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap}
 * @param tag {T}
 * @param id {string}
 * @returns {HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]}
 */
function createNode(tag,id) {
    let newNode = document.createElement(tag)
    newNode.id = id;
    return newNode;
}
```

(See also: [Document generic type parameters in JSDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017627/11107541))

Your attempt to use the `as` (type assertion) keyword didn't work because that's not JavaScript syntax. It's TypeScript syntax. You can use type annotations in JavaScript with JSDoc using `@type {...}`.

Comment: The solution you proposed for the JS Doc worked, and now VSC is offering methods. I don' really understand why but Its working. It is frustrating to search for an hour for a solution to a problem that is really silly and not be able to, and the worst of all is that your solution works, but I really do not understand much of what you say, because you use concepts that are new to me as static analysis. This makes it even more frustrating because even with the solution in front of me I am not able to understand what is going on.
I guess I have to keep studying :).
Thanks for your answer & time.

Comment: @Alfonsoz yes. have some grit. keep at it! don't let your frustration get the best of you. learn more. everyone goes through the learning process and some say it never really ends. you'll get the hang of it. experimentation and documentation are your friends. (you're welcome).